# Parsing JSON vs parsing XML in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, json, xml-parsing

Scenario :

I am working on a parser for data which is sent back from a server after making a request. The format of data is either JSON or XML.

Question:

1. Are there any reasons to choose one of these formats over the other one?
2. Which one is faster, parsing json or parsing xml?

Thanks all.

Comment: You may find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152700/what-type-of-webservice-works-best-with-ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project) about parsing XMLs. I might sound opinionated, but if there's a choice go for JSON, although I have no clue what situation your project is in. I would certainly look at the entire architecture (trade-offs and choices) of the project before making a decision. From my experience, understanding JSON and relating it to NSDictionaries and NSArrays is much easier than understanding XMLs.

Answer (score 3):

When JSON is preferred it is usually because it is significantly shorter. That saves transmission traffic and therefore time and battery power (not a bad thing, though?). 
Meaning: Even if parsing JSON would be slower (which I doubt), the gain during the tranfer over the air would certainly compensate any additional CPU time during parsing.

Answer (score 1):

THis is a useful [post](http://www.mnot.net/blog/2012/04/13/json_or_xml_just_decide) that might help you decide.