# Need to know about web based client server app for iPhone

Tags: mysql, ios, iphone, uiwebview

I want to develop a web based client server application for iPhone. I need to develop a database on server in MySQL for example to store some data and pictures etc. And then develop a web application for iPhone using UIWebView or something to connect to server and extract the data and pictures from the database on server and display on the iPhone screen. (just a website). Is it it possible with MySQL and PHP, or I have to use SQL Server or some other DBMS? What is needed for me?? Any tutorials, suggestions etc??? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the familiar with the objective-c language and iOS sdk to connect with the server from your iOS app. good starting point would be to start with apple developer site(developer.apple.com) or  [ray wenderlich tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials).You can show your webpage inside iOS app using web view but if you want to set a UI for your data and pictures then you need to use iOS tools like UITableView or UICollectionView and create your custom UI. For connecting the server and getting data you can use this tutorial [how to create a web service](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service)

Comment: Okay. I'll consider this for sure. I know Objective-C, iOS SDK, and some iPhone programming. I just want to know that we'll have to use some web services for client and server communication for mobiles and receive data in XML or JSON?? Or we can do the normal client server programming like we're developing websites. Taking data from table and display or use in a webpage. Insert records from the webpage to the table and update etc..??? Waiting for your response...

Comment: it's similar to how we do it in websites, just in case of mobiles you need to parse the data in xml or json format and send it to the iOS app from server. Inside iOS app you need to request for the data to the server and in response server will send the data, data will be in json or xml format, so use some parsing library like AFNetwokring https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking or Apple's NSXML or NSJSONSerialisation class and parse the data. use this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/ and http://www.raywenderlich.com/30445/afnetworking-crash-course#

Comment: Thanks for the nice answers. One more question, because I'm confused. What is parsing of XML or JSON, and what is serialization? What's the difference between these two? when to do which one? which one is better or better in any special condition or situation etc???? thanks

Comment: JSon Serialization means to convert JSON to Foundation objects like Dictionary or Array. It's same for the XML Data as well ie Xml to NSDictionary or NSArray. XML parsing and Serialisation are refered to the same thing. read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971487/parsing-json-vs-parsing-xml-in-ios and http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. can I send images and videos also along with data in XML or JSON from server to iPhone??? Any tutorial on sending images and/or videos and data in JSON from server to iPhone. thanks

Comment: no you can't send images and videos in json, you need to send the url of the image in json and request for that image using another method. this link can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186854/download-a-file-image-with-afnetworking-in-ios