# Is CORBA still being widely used today?

Tags: corba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Corba Legacy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226050/is-corba-legacy)

I am asking this question because I don't see any new books on CORBA in recent years. I am really new to CORBA, and I am not sure if I still need to learn it.
In what situation, CORBA is still useful?

Comment: See [Is Corba Legacy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226050/is-corba-legacy).

Answer (score 2):

My last job at a defense contractor used CORBA heavily.  (And ACE/TAO)

I have only used it at one job of about 8 in the last 15 years.  It was talked about at a few other places I was at - but none used it.