# Is CORBA a language?

Tags: corba, language-interoperability

As i know CORBA is used to maintain interoperability in distributed systems by acting in middle.

What i want to know is, **is CORBA a language which has its own syntax of coding** or **do we code in CORBA using other languages like C#, Java etc.**

I went through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226050/is-corba-legacy) but didn't find a direct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latter; you create CORBA implementations in a programming language such as C# or Java.

Comment: The language of implementation (but in this case it was an awkward usage so I corrected it).

Answer (score 4):

[CORBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture) is not a language, it's a request broker architecture.

Basically, it defines and provides a common calling protocol so code written in different languages can call one another's functions.

Answer (score 2):

CORBA is standard for distributed objects. Part of that standard is IDL - Interface Definiton Language. So one part of CORBA is language, but keep in mind this is not programming language, but declarative one used to define structure of interacion of object in a distrubuted system.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture), not a language.

Answer (score 1):

CORBA is not a programming language, it is a standard that defines how programs communicate with objects (how they send objects and to which objects/methods they send them). It defines how such objects are represented and how they are transmitted.

One of CORBA's specificities is that it is designed to allow programs written in different programming languages (or in the same language but running on different implementations, for that matter) to communicate.

Answer (score 0):

The Common Object Request Broker Architecture (CORBA) is a standard defined by the Object Management Group (OMG) that enables software components written in multiple computer languages and running on multiple computers to work together (i.e., it supports multiple platforms).

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corba

It help to google a little around before asking...

Comment: Yeah that's the first thing i did. But anywhere it is not mentioned whether it is a language or not.

Answer (score 0):

Shortly you may call it IBM's COM.

Answer (score 0):

**Direct Answer:** **No it is not a language.**

**More details:**

**Introduction**

In older days most of the computer systems was legacy or centralized. But when the people began to develop large computer based system they have to go to another architecture called as distribute computer system architecture. Designers of distributed systems have to organize their system designs to find a balance between performance, dependability, security, and manageability of the system. There is no universal model of system organization that is appropriate for all circumstances so various distributed
architectural styles have emerged. Some of distributed system architectures are:

- Master-slave architecture
- Two-tier client–server architecture
- Multitier client–server architecture
- Distributed component(Object) architecture
- Peer-to-peer architecture

  **Image of Distributed Component Architecture**

Before came the distributed component architecture, most of the systems used layered architecture which limits the flexibility of system designers and they have to decide what services should be include in each services. But in practically this was given a big headache to the system designers because in some situation that cannot be identify clearly weather a service is database, data management or application. To avoid this situation there image distributed object/component architecture which design the system as set of services against to older layered architecture.
In this architecture, each component provide separate independent services to the system. These components totally depend on middleware’s because middleware provide facility to communicate with each object even though one component to other component located in a different platform. Normally middleware manages component interactions, reconciles differences between types of the parameters passed between components, and provides a set of common services that application components can use. For example consider the following figure. Although there interconnect several platforms (may be hardware of software), system can communicate successfully by using the middleware.

Common Object Request Broker (CORBA) is the practical implementation of the implementation of middleware in industrial level. Middleware for distributed computing is required at two levels called logical level and component level. CORBA defined component standards in the component level of middleware. COBA uses IIOP as its standard protocol and a CORBA-based program from any vendor, on almost any computer, operating system, programming language, and network, can interoperate with a CORBA-based program from the same or another vendor, on almost any other computer, operating system, programming language, and network.

For complete article,please visit the blog:
http://articlesofte.blogspot.com/